# Make WPF TextBlock non clickable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've got a simple UserControl with a TextBlock and two buttons.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="30" Text="Please install updates" Foreground="#FFF" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,0,0,20" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="Restart Now" Margin="5 0 0 0" Width="80" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Content="Snooze" Width="60" Height="25" Margin="10 0 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="bttnOK_Click" />
</Grid>
```

For some reason TextBlock is clickable and when you click it, it closes the control.
[image]

Desired behavior: Non clickable TextBlock. When clicking TextBlock, control stays open.

Comment: normally they are non-clickable. Maybe you have a style that overwrites the default properties? One where it sets `IsCancel` to `true`.

Comment: Can you give more details about the parent object / Styles?

Comment: I just copied your XAML in to a brand new project, and the `Textblock` is *not* clickable.  The problem must be someplace else.

Comment: This UserControl is inside telerik DesktopAlert, maybe this is what causing the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you have added `<TextBlock ... Grid.RowSpan=2/>` which makes the TextBlock enter the region of Buttons.
Alternatively if removing the RowSpan in TextBlock doesn't solve the issue, try adding `IsHitTestVisible=false` to TextBlock.

It looks like this,

```
<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="30" Text="Please install updates" Foreground="#FFF" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,0,0,20"/>
<Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="Restart Now" Margin="5 0 0 0" Width="80" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
<Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Content="Snooze" Width="60" Height="25" Margin="10 0 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="bttnOK_Click" />
```

Comment: Even with RowSpan=2 the Buttons are still on top of the TextBlock. So what's the point?

Comment: Visually they are..., but it might be that the Buttons border may have expanded till the TextBlock. Or it could be that the container you are enclosing this UserControl is clickable. Try adding IsHitTestVisible=false to the container.

Comment: IsHitTestVisible="False" helped. Thanks a lot!